# How to find lowest field from List Array

Tags: java

Can someone please advise how I can find the lowest student id from the List object?

I got Student class:

```
public class Student{
private int id;
private String name;

..Getter and setters
```

Main class:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student(105, "John");
        Student s2 = new Student(101, "Peter");
        Student s3 = new Student(108, "Simon");
        Student s4 = new Student(103, "Jo");

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.add(s1);
        students.add(s2);
        students.add(s3);
        students.add(s4);
```

How I can retrieve the minimum student id from the list?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: By iterating through the IDs of all the elements of the List?

Comment: You'll need a variable to hold the lowest ID you've encountered so far in the list.  Initialize it to null.  Now, loop through every item in the list.   Is it lower than the previous lowest (or is the previous low == null)?  If so, that's your new low.

Comment: This is no different than any other "find the minimum X in a list/array". Please show us what you've attempted, and what you're having problems with specifically.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking that someone will suggest me to use Collections, rather than looping...

Answer (score 1):

The fastest (computationally) way of doing this would be to just take one pass through the list and keep track of the min:

```
Integer min = null;
for (Student student : students) {
    if (min == null || student.getId() < min) {
        min = student.getId();
    }
}
```

then the minimum student id would be stored in `min`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Iterator<Student> itr = students.iterator();
Student min_student = itr.next();
Student curr_student;
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    curr_student = itr.next();
    if (curr_student.getId() < min_student.getID()) {
        min_student = curr_student;
    }
}
```

// min_student here will be the one with minimum id.